# When trying to create a release pipeline in Azure DevOps (I have used a Nodejs application) it exits with an error. ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, azure-devops

NodeJs application that I have been trying to deploy, always shows an error:

> [error]Bash exited with code '1'.

```
{

    "name": "test1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node app.js",
      "dev": "nodemon app.js",
      "build": " "
    },
     "keywords": ["app.js"],
     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC",
     "dependencies": {
     "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
     "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
     "ejs": "^2.6.2",
     "express": "^4.17.1",
     "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.5.0",
     "express-session": "^1.16.2",
     "i": "^0.3.6",
     "mongoose": "^5.6.5",
     "passport": "^0.4.0",
     "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Please check the path in the artifacts weather the files that are required exists in the artifacts or not. Download the artifact that you are trying to deploy and make sure the package.json and app.js is in the **root directory** (or in the deirectory that you are trying to deploy).

For further diagnoisis i think you need to provide your question with more detail descriptions like

1. What build script was used to make the artifact.
2. What environment was used for app deployment.